# Does the reverse function take exactly one argument (a string)?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

The following function is an attempt to reverse a string.
The code raise  an exception

`'str' object does not support item assignment` error.

**Code**

```
text =''
def reverse(text):
    r=text
    m=len(text)-1
    for i in (r):
        r[m]=i
        m-=1
    return sum(r)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear. Please state it clearly, in full, in your main text rather than in the title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python how reverse a string

Comment: @cool477 check the anser

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work correctly for a mutable sequence, either; did you test it at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason for Exception**
The reason for the error is that in python string is immutable

**Logic problem**
The code won't work for even on a mutable list type.The code has several logical errors

**Solution in detail**

string is immutable in python, you can not use

```
   r[index]= value
```

The above code is invalid

for reverse you may do

```
def reverse(text):
    return text[::-1]
```

**Optimal solution**

Its worth arguing if `slicing` or `reversed` is better.Both are not a fair comparison as `reversed` returns an iterator

Here is my comparison anyways done using [ipython](https://ipython.org)

```
In [13]: %timeit  "sarath"[::-1]
The slowest run took 14.82 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 257 ns per loop

In [14]: %timeit "".join(reversed("sarath"))
The slowest run took 9.02 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.32 µs per loop
```

Comment: Ideally you would use "reversed" as it is more readable and probably faster (not checked).

Comment: @Frogboxe reversed return a sequence not the string. so it adds more space and complecxity and more time

Comment: @Frogboxe i have updated the commparison of both the approach in the answer

Comment: @Frogboxe: Using `[::-1]` to get the reverse of a sequence is, like it or not, the common Python idiom. `reversed` is only superior when you need to iterate over it without copying, and even then, it's only better for reduced memory use, most of the time, the `[::-1]` slice will be faster too.